# python module variable confusion

Tags: python

Here is my code :

a module settings.py:

```
My_KEY = ""
```

and I am using this MY_KEY in another module

my_module.py

```
from settings import My_KEY


def function_a():
    MY_KEY = "abcd"


def function_b():
    function_a();
    print My_KEY
```

I expect to see a "abcd" in output when I call function_b(), but how come I get empty string. I am totally lost

Comment: If you want to explicitly change the module level variable it's clearer and more explicit to do it directly:  import settings and then settings.MY_KEY = 'abcd' makes it clear that you wanted to change the variable.  BTW it's a convention to use ALL_CAPS for constants that don't change, so it's doubly confusing here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, when an assignment statement is encountered inside a function, Python takes the variable on the left-hand side to be a local variable.

If you want to modify a global variable from within a function, use the [`global` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) to declare the variable to be a global:

```
def function_a():
    global My_KEY
    My_KEY = "abcd"
```

However, it is better to avoid modifying globals from within functions. In the long run it makes code harder to understand. You could instead pass `My_KEY` as a return value from `function_a`:

```
def function_a():
    My_KEY = "abcd"
    return My_KEY

def function_b():
    My_KEY = function_a()
    print My_KEY
```

Answer (score 3):

It's all about python [scoping and namespacing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

You have actually 3 versions of `My_KEY`:

- global variable `My_KEY` imported
- `My_KEY` in `function_a` (I think you have a typo there: should be `My_KEY` instead of `MY_KEY`)
- `My_KEY` in `function_b`

You can mark variable inside a function as `global` in order to modify it:

```
def function_a():
    global My_KEY
    My_KEY = "abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoping is part of the issue but you also need to be careful about how you import variables. `from settings import My_KEY` creates a new variable in the local module's namespace that points to the original string. When you assign a different string to your module's My_KEY, that doesn't affect the My_KEY in the settings module. Its not a problem when you are modifying mutable objects, but any time you reassign a value, You are better off just importing the module the module itself and using the variable's dotted name.

settings.py:

```
My_KEY = ""
```

then a quick test in the shell

```
>>> from settings import My_KEY
>>> def function_a():
...     global My_KEY
...     My_KEY="abcd"
... 
>>> My_KEY
''
>>> function_a()
>>> My_KEY
'abcd'
>>> 
>>> # here's where it gets funky... the original settings.My_KEY didn't change 
>>> 
>>> import settings
>>> settings.My_KEY
''
>>>
```